# How to convert blob to png or jpg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, blob

I have used **react-images-zoom-print**  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-zoom-print  I am taking a photo of the API with a blob like this:

```
     const downloadDepositMoneyInfosClickHandler = (row) => {
       props.service(row.id, (status, data) => {
          var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/png" });
          var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          imageRef.current = objectUrl;
          setImgDialogOpen(true);
        });
      };

>    console.log(imageRef.current)==>
         blob:http://localhost:3000/c85aiua36d-2fua-43a8-a881-311d287ed37e
```

and in Lightbox:

```
       <Lightbox
            images={[{src:"'"+imageRef.current+"'"}]}
            isOpen={imgDialogOpen}
            onClose={closeImgDialog}
            rotatable={true}
            zoomable={true}
            onPrint={() => window.print()}
          />
```

But it does not show it, I think it should become a `png` or `jpg`.
I want to turn it into a photo with the type `png` or `jpg`.

How should I convert it?

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
const blobToImage = (blob) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
      resolve(img)
    }
    img.src = url
  })
}
```